# firebase database - It takes an hour for all callbacks to be triggered - what went wrong?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am connecting to firebase database

1. Using an android service to interact with firebase.
2. Using anonymous authentication. No issues with authentication. (permissions set correctly, SHA-1s updated, latest google-service.json, etc.)
3. From India. I understand that the server is located in US. But my Internet connection is very good.

This service is started in two scenarios:

1. Whenever internet connection becomes available
2. Whenever application is freshly opened

In the first scenario, when application is not running, I find that all the callbacks get called. (not very fast, takes about a minute or two)

In the second scenario, for all the callbacks to happen it takes a lot of time, like about an hour!

I don't understand why it takes so much time. Here is the code:

```
public class FirebaseService extends Service {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        firebaseInit();
    }

    private void firebaseInit() {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    Timber.d("onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    return;
                }

                Timber.d("onAuthStateChanged:signed_in: %s", user.getUid());
                ensureInfoIsPersistedInDbAsync(user);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Timber.d("service starting.");

        // NOTE: Though this is async operation, 
        //       all is executed by only one thread: main thread.

        // write and/or retrieve info1 and info2
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        signInAsync();

        // Why START_STICKY?
        // If service is killed prematurely,
        //    automatic restart done by system when possible.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void signInAsync() {
        mAuth.signInAnonymously()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Timber.d("signInAnonymously:onComplete:isSuccessful: %s", task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                            stopSelf();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void ensureInfoIsPersistedInDbAsync(FirebaseUser user) {
        final DatabaseReference info1Node = getUserIdNode(user).child(INFO1_NODE);

        info1Node.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Timber.d("info1 in db: %s", dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    ensureInfo2IsPersistedInDbAsync();
                } else {
                    Timber.d("saving info1 %s", LOCALINFO_1);
                    info1Node.setValue(LOCALINFO_1)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    ensureInfo2IsPersistedInDbAsync();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Timber.d("updating or checking info1 is cancelled.");
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ensureInfo2IsPersistedInDbAsync() {
        final DatabaseReference info2Node = getUserIdNode(user).child(INFO2_NODE);

        info2Node.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Timber.d("info2 in db: %s", dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    stopSelf();
                } else {
                    Timber.d("saving info2 in db.");
                    info2Node.setValue(LOCAL_INFO2);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Timber.d("updating or checking info2 is cancelled.");
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }

    private DatabaseReference getUserIdNode(FirebaseUser user) {
        return getDbRoot()
                .child(USERS)
                .child(user.getUid());
    }
}
```

Here the the log output (for scenario 2):

```
06-08 18:05:04.072 8341-8341/com.example.app D/FirebaseService: service starting.
06-08 18:05:04.125 8341-8341/com.example.app D/FirebaseService: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
06-08 18:05:05.897 8341-8341/com.example.app D/FirebaseService: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
06-08 18:05:05.948 8341-8341/com.example.app D/FirebaseService: onAuthStateChanged:signed_in: <bla bla>
06-08 18:05:05.951 8341-8341/com.example.app D/FirebaseService: signInAnonymously:onComplete:isSuccessful: true
06-08 18:07:20.747 8341-8341/com.example.app D/FirebaseService: saving info1 <bla bla>
<after long long long time> saving info2 in db: <bla bla>
```

Take a look at all the threads currently running. Main thread is quite available to process call back if that happens. I also see FirebaseDatabaseWorker is waiting on something.

```
"FirebaseDatabaseWorker@5201" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FirebaseDatabaseWorker@5201
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x1471> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2055)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1060)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:776)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"pool-1-thread-1@5200" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks pool-1-thread-1@5200
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x1470> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"TubeSockWriter-12@5205" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks TubeSockWriter-12@5205
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x1473> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2016)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
      at anl.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:126)
      at anl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:141)
      at anm.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1022)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"TubeSockReader-12@5204" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(NativeCrypto.java:-1)
      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:699)
      - locked <0x1472> (a java.lang.Object)
      at libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:81)
      at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:99)
      at ank.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:141)
      at ank.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:34)
      at anb.d(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:371)
      at and.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1028)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"main@5189" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-1)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

"FinalizerDaemon@5192" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FinalizerDaemon@5192
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
      - locked <0x146b> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"GoogleApiCleanup@5199" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks GoogleApiCleanup@5199
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:101)
      - locked <0x146f> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
      at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:72)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj$zzb.run(Unknown Source:-1)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@5193" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks FinalizerWatchdogDaemon@5193
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:240)
      - locked <0x146c> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
      at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:212)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon@5191" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks ReferenceQueueDaemon@5191
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:134)
      - locked <0x10de> (a java.lang.Class)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"HeapTrimmerDaemon@5194" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks HeapTrimmerDaemon@5194
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:311)
      - locked <0x146d> (a java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"GCDaemon@5195" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks GCDaemon@5195
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run(Daemons.java:344)
      - locked <0x146e> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

"GoogleApiHandler@5198" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-1)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

"Signal Catcher@5190" daemon prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder_1@5196" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder_2@5197" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"RenderThread@5202" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended

"Binder_3@5203" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     Incompatible thread state: thread not suspended
```

What is it that I am doing wrong that firebase real time database is responding very slowly? In one case, couple of minutes, and in another case about an hour!

Comment: Remove all callback before call to second service

Comment: Call to the first service itself is behaving like this.

Comment: FWIW: I copy/pasted your code and made the minor edits to get it to compile (added empty `onBind()` and moved `user` to class field).  When I run it I don't see the delays (I'm in California).  Seems like it's a network issue.  The Firebase debug logs are very detailed.  You might get some insights if you enable them: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)`.  Also, I'm curious why you are using a completion task for `info1Node.setValue()` instead of `CompletionListener`.  I'm not saying there is anything wrong with using the task, but is the added thread needed?

Comment: @qbix That's interesting. I don't intent to use another thread. I want everything to run on main thread since I don't want to worry about thread safely since in the actual code I am using fields. I didn't realize that we can pass `CompletionListener` to setValue.

Comment: That did the trick! Replacing `onCompleteListener` with `CompletionListener` makes it work. I get the callback almost immediately. Could it be a bug in firebase or some issue with my code here. In any case, thanks a ton. firebase Logging you suggested is also pretty useful.

Comment: Well, on another device (nexus 4), I see the original problem even with updated code. That device is known to have connectivity issues. Firebase log shows that the websocket connection is timed out for some reason. I wonder if there is anything client can do to recreate the connection.